# Can a Xamarin Android bindings library behave like 'compileOnly' in gradle?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to write a Xamarin Android binding library for a library that is loaded in the app during runtime. When using this library in a normal Android project, you would use "compileOnly".

```
compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82'
compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources'
```

[From my understanding](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies), "compileOnly" makes the code from the library available for compilation but does not add it to the resulting apk. Meaning it needs to be provided in runtime for the app to work.

When reading the [Xamarin binding Build Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/#build-actions) docs, "compileOnly" sounds very similar to "InputJar".

> Does not embed the .jar into the resulting Bindings Library .DLL. Your Bindings Library .DLL will have a dependency on this .jar at runtime. Use this option when you do not want to include the .jar in your Bindings Library (for example, for licensing reasons). If you use this option, you must ensure that the input .jar is available on the device that runs your app.

However, when compiling my application while using methods provided by the runtime library, I get errors from the generated java code that the packages do not exist.

> javac.exe error :  error: package de.robv.android.xposed does not exist
>   javac.exe error :       de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage
>   javac.exe error :  error: package de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage does not exist
>   javac.exe error :   public void handleLoadPackage (de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam p0)
>   error :  error: package de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage does not exist
>   error :     private native void n_handleLoadPackage (de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam p0);

Meaning that the code was not made available during compilation. How can I make sure the code is made available during compilation but not embedded into application?

Comment: Most SDK’s will also reference other Java files. So did you check reference in *.pom file with your java file. And you check the  settings of linker for your application? You can set it to None.Here is a link about the creating Xamarin.Android Binding Library.https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-xamarin-android-binding-library/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT The jar file I am trying to use has no other dependencies. The missing packages are from the jar itself. I tried "None" and "Sdk and User Assemblies" but both did not work. Here is the project that does not compile https://github.com/AeonLucid/XamarinTest.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973909/4374462

Either using `AndroidExternalJavaLibrary` or `[assembly: Java.Interop.DoNotPackage("ref.jar")]`.