# Xamarin binding library combination of InputJar and ReferenceJar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use https://github.com/Redth/Xamarin.Android.Xposed in Xamarin but the final result is rejected by Xposed, saying: "cannot load module" .. "the xposed api classes are compiled into the module's apk". The xposed-api.jar file is currently a `EmbeddedJar`, which is what causes that error. The xposed-api.jar file is made available during **run-time** by Xposed already.

From the [xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

> InputJar – Does not embed the .jar into the resulting Bindings Library .DLL. Your Bindings Library .DLL will have a dependency on this .jar at **runtime**.

InputJar seems like it will solve my issue with it being compiled into the resulting apk. However, it can't compile into an apk at all. It gives me errors in the generated java file such as.

> JAVAC0000:  error: package de.robv.android.xposed does not exist
>           de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage           0

Then for ReferenceJar..

> ReferenceJar – Specifies a reference .jar: a reference .jar is a .jar that one of your bound .jar or .AAR files depends on. This reference .jar is used only to satisfy **compile-time** dependencies. When you use this build action, C# bindings are not created for the reference .jar and it is not embedded in the resulting Bindings Library .DLL.

Great, it will provide it during compile-time.. however, no bindings will be generated so I can't use it.

I also tried combining these by creating 2 identical libraries with one having InputJar and the other ReferenceJar, but that did not work at all.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

To sum it up, I need to add xposed-api.jar as a library just like how android.jar of the Android framework is added. You can use the classes and compile properly, without the classes being compiled into the apk.

Answer (score 0):

OK, The trick is actually "AndroidExternalJavaLibrary".

Imagine you have a Jar binding project XPosedAPI, and an Android project XposedSample.

The structure would be:

```
XPosedAPI
|-- Jar
    |-- api-82.jar (InputJar)

XposedSample
|-- Jar
    |-- api-82.jar (AndroidExternalJavaLibrary)
```

You see, the trick is you have to put the same jar file for each project.
For the Jar binding project, it has to be "InputJar" - that's used to generate the C# binding dll.

For the project that using the Jar bindng dll, the jar has to be "AndroidExternalJavaLibrary". This ensures the javac compile process.

There was an easier way, the `Java.Interop.DoNotPackageAttribute`.
You just put the below line on one of these projects (just put it on XPosedAPI project would be enough), and it works:

```
[assembly: Java.Interop.DoNotPackage("api-82.jar")]
```

However, this attribute is marked as "[deprecated](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/c739a6069888c36ec16402573cb0efe36caf8ea8/Documentation/guides/messages/xa0122.md)", although it's easier.

I figured out this, because I'm trying to do the same thing - write a xposed module in C#.

The Xamarin.Android.Xposed project looks nice, but in fact it won't work, and there are much more problems to be fixed besides the jar binding issue.

I think I'm getting closer, and I may publish it in a few days if I can fix all the bugs remained.
If you're interested, watch my project: https://github.com/UlyssesWu/XamarinPosed